# jQuery autocomplete with categories, selection and focus not working and list format incorrect

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm having a h... of a time figuring out why my **jQuery autocomplete** with categories and formatted results is not working. I've gone through a bunch of the similar questions on SO and tried every suggestion that I could find, but nothing seems to be working.

While the display is correct, it is not appending the list items to the top ul. It adds one, and then each subsequent result is appended to the same list item. This means that focus and selection methods do not work as intended.

**I've tried:**

- `_renderItemData(ul, item)` vs. `_renderItem(ul, item)`
- With and without the `.data("item.autocomplete", item)` in `renderItem()`
- Appending `.data("item.autocomplete", {})` to the `ul.append` in the
  renderMenu method
- Changing the class used in the category list item.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here's the full code and the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4dJev/2/):

```
$(function () {
  function format(item) {
    var cell = '';

    $.each(item.value, function(index, value) {
      cell += "<a class='ui-autocomplete-thumbnail-link' href='" + value.url + "'>";

      cell += "<img class='ui-autocomplete-thumbnail-image' src='" + value.images.small + "' />";

      cell += value.presentation + "</a>";
    });

    return cell;
  }

  $.widget( "custom.categorycomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
      var self = this, current_category = '';

      $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        if (item.label !== current_category) {
          current_category = item.label;
          ul.append($("<li class='ui-category'>" + current_category + "</li>").data("item.autocomplete", {}));
        }

        self._renderItem(ul, item);
      });
    }
  });

var    jsondata = [
    {
        "value": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "category1-name1",
                "presentation": "category1-presentation1",
                "url": "example.com/category1-url1",
                "images": {
                    "small": "http://sipi.usc.edu/database/preview/misc/4.1.07.png"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "category1-name2",
                "presentation": "category1-presentation2",
                "url": "example.com/category1-url2",
                "images": {
                    "small": "http://sipi.usc.edu/database/preview/misc/4.1.08.png"
                }
            }
        ],
        "label": "category1"
    },
    {
        "value": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "category2-name1",
                "presentation": "category2-presentation1",
                "url": "example.com/category2-url1",
                "images": {
                    "small": "http://sipi.usc.edu/database/preview/misc/4.1.01.png"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "category2-name2",
                "presentation": "category2-presentation2",
                "url": "example.com/category2-url2",
                "images": {
                    "small": "http://sipi.usc.edu/database/preview/misc/4.1.03.png"
                }
            }
        ],
        "label": "category2"
    }
];

  $('#s1').categorycomplete({
    source: jsondata,
    select: function (event, ui) {
      window.location.href = ui.item.value[0].url.replace(window.location.host, '');

      return false;
    }
  })
  .data( "categorycomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li>" )
    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append(format(item))
    .appendTo(ul);
  };
});
```

Comment: why do you have nested items? Since you now create two `<a>` in each `LI` will of course throw off presentation and events bound to LI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this, note restructured JSON:

```
$(function () {
  function format(item) {
    var cell = '';   
      cell += "<a data-url='"+item.url+"' class='ui-autocomplete-thumbnail-link' '>";
      cell += "<img class='ui-autocomplete-thumbnail-image' src='" + item.images.small + "' />";
      cell += item.name + "</a>";  

    return cell;
  }

  $.widget( "custom.categorycomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
      var self = this, current_category = '';

      $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        if (item.label !== current_category) {
          current_category = item.label;
          ul.append($("<li class='ui-category'>" + current_category + "</li>").data("item.autocomplete", {}));
        }

        self._renderItem(ul, item);
      });
    }
  });

var jsondata = [
{
    "label": "category1-presentation1",
    "value": "category1-presentation1",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "category1-name1",
    "url": "example.com/category1-url1",
    "images": {
        "small": "http://sipi.usc.edu/database/preview/misc/4.1.07.png"
    }
},
{
    "value": "category1-presentation2",
    "label": "category1-presentation2",
    "id": 2,
    "name": "category1-name2",
    "url": "example.com/category1-url2",
    "images": {
        "small": "http://sipi.usc.edu/database/preview/misc/4.1.08.png"
    }
},
{
    "value": "category2-presentation1",
    "label": "category2-presentation1",
    "id": 3,
    "name": "category2-name1",
    "url": "example.com/category2-url1",
    "images": {
        "small": "http://sipi.usc.edu/database/preview/misc/4.1.01.png"
    }
}, 
{
    "value": "category2-presentation2",
    "label": "category2-presentation2",
    "id": 4,
    "name": "category2-name2",
    "url": "example.com/category2-url2",
    "images": {
        "small": "http://sipi.usc.edu/database/preview/misc/4.1.03.png"
    }
}
];

  $('#s1').categorycomplete({
    source: jsondata,
    select: function (event, ui) {

        $(this).val('')
        alert('Url is:'+ ui.item.url.replace(window.location.host, ''))


      return false;
    }
  })
  .data( "categorycomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li>" )
    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append(format(item))
    .appendTo(ul);
  };
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xQEsK/

Comment: Thanks! While the JSON validated, it wasn't the correct format.

Comment: Not yours, mine. I thought all was well as it was valid, just didn't realize that it was not structured properly for autocomplete. In retrospect, it was a silly thing to overlook.